# How to upgrade istio 1.4.3 to latest with zero downtime

Tags: upgrade, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, istio, aws-application-load-balancer

I am newly hired engineer who started working with istio recently. My application is currently running on istio 1.4.3 and having issues when i tried to upgrade to latest using istioctl upgrade.

Below are the steps i tried

1) Verified the versions using istioctl version and saw that control plane and data plane are running on 1.4.3 whereas client version is 1.5.1 (the version i planned to upgrade).

2) Tried istioctl upgrade and seen a message “cannot upgrade because of mismatch of versions in istio components”.

3) As it was my dev environment, i decided to reinstall using istioctl manifest apply --profile default

4) Above step cost me a lot of time, because i lost all the settings related to ingress gateway connected to AWS ALB, instead ingress controller created a classic load balancer which is not part of our previous set-up.

5) I also lost setting related to prometheus, grafana, kiali.

6) Now i am planning upgrade my prod without messing the current settings, please suggest a correct way to upgrade istio to latest version with zero downtime.

what is the best way to do this upgrade, can you point out any link to documentation apart from what is mentioned in istio website ? Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> can you point out any link to documentation apart from what is mentioned in istio website

https://istio.io has the most comprehensive information on the topic.

There are some [prerequisites](https://istio.io/docs/setup/upgrade/#upgrade-prerequisites) for the Istio upgrade as well.
- Istio version 1.4.4 or higher is installed.
- Your Istio installation was installed using istioctl.

It looks like your Istio version is a tiny step below minimum supported one :)

> what is the best way to do this upgrade,

Usually it is recommended to go  1.4 --> 1.5 and only then 1.5 --> 1.6.

I have found the following [document](https://istio.io/pt-br/docs/setup/upgrade/istioctl-upgrade/) that describes an "experimental feature, which is intended for evaluation purposes only".
But the minimal version for it is 1.3.3 or higher, which might do the trick for you.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The last link you mentioned in the reply seems to be removed and placed somewhere else. I too found its hard to upgrade 1.4.3 directly. Hence created a default.yaml file and upgraded it to 1.5.4 and fortunately it went well.

Regards
Karthik