# How to rollback Istio to the old control plane, instead of completing the canary upgrade?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, istio, istio-sidecar

We were doing a test on Canary upgrade of our Istio setup from `1.7.3` to `1.8.6` version.

So we installed canary version `1-8-6` for the istio controlplane and we mapped one namespace to the upgraded version. We tested the application and we were getting 200 response.

Everything was working as expected till this point. So in order to try a rollback, we just went to the document but the steps are not clear enough regarding the rollback.

[image]

What is the method to reinstall the gateway here? We used `istioctl` with overlay and default profile for `v1.7.3` installation. So, how to reinstall the gatway?

After uninstalling the canary version, the ingress gateway pods got removed and our application got down with a `500` error.

So would like to clear about the exact process to rollback from canary version to previous installed version.
But due to some issues, we want to rollback to previous version.

Comment: @nk_nodejs_training i went through this but didnt help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062694/how-to-upgrade-istio-1-4-3-to-latest-with-zero-downtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do

```text
istioctl x uninstall --revision=canary
```

if you successfully upgraded. This command should only be used if you decided to stop upgrading in the middle of the process, and want to go back.

To downgrade to a lower version of Istio you should use
`istioctl upgrade`. Steps are identical to actual upgrade procedure, you just have to use `istioctl` binary corresponding to a lower version.
You can find more in the [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/in-place/#downgrade-prerequisites).

---

If you still want to go with `istioctl x uninstall`, and to answer your question:

> reinstall the gateway(s) for the previous revision manually

means install your gateways the same way you did when deploying Istio for the first time. If you used the default configuration, and did not create any custom gateways, you can just use yaml files that come with the installation files of lower version.

Comment: can you give some more details on why we souldnt use istioctl x uninstall --revision=canary if we upgraded succesfully. What will be the problem if we use it. Also if we use istioctl upgrade to downgrade the version, i think its inplace method and we shouldnt take this in a production environment..please correct me